# awful.util.spawn executes the command twice - Awesome WM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I have written `awful.util.spawn("vncviewer")` in `rc.lua.` But this results in two `vncviewer` instances (windows) in the startup. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Without more details, my guess is as good as yours. However the odds are that you put the line in a signal callback that gets called twice (like for each screen or something).

Can you pastebin your `rc.lua` in a comment so I can update my message with a more accurate answer?